# DDR2-667 compatability in conjunction with DDR2-800

Tags: memory, ddr2

I have a DDR2-800 RAM in one of the slots of 2. [Here it shows DDR-800 only as upgradable in the other slot](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=Vostro%201015).

Would DDR2-667 work in the other slot? Or will it be incompatible?

Comment: Apart from it being notably slower and inconsistent in its speed, yes it will work

Comment: Thanks. I dont know whether I should create new question but where do I find the motherboard information? Model showing using 'lshw' command in ubuntu is 047MWF

Comment: Do some research eg. [This](http://bit.ly/19wtpVZ) and [this](http://bit.ly/19wtxF2) search to find the information your after. If after that you still cannot find the information you need consider asking a new question [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the other properties of the RAM. It is likely that the `RAM Timings` will be different and the motherboard will probably default to the slower RAMs settings. The timings for one of the RAM modules may not be compatible with the timings of the other, which would be problematic as your system may not boot up.

Another factor that may come into play is the voltage required to run each RAM module.

I wouldn't risk it personally. Try and find RAM with similar specs just to be on the safe side.